# jquery .each() function taking effect on browser "go back" button only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a webpage where I'm loading a div from another page using .load(). After I do the loading I run some jquery code to append a specific url to all the existing hrefs. The issue is that the first time I click on a hyperlink/href I am redirected to the old href. But after I click the "go back" button on my browser, and I try the same hyperlink/href, the href works and takes me to the new appended href.

I would like to see if there is anyway to have all my hrefs change when I first load the page.

Here is my code:

**1st** I initialize the container where I will be loading the container from the second page.

```html
<pre>
  <code id="iframe-fragment"></code>
</pre>
```

**2nd** I load the second page's container into my current webpage.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/rsi_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
  $('#iframe-fragment').load('https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/_absolute_motion_8cs-example.html div.fragment'); 
</script>
```

**3rd** I append a url to all the hrefs in the imported container.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);       
      var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
      $this.attr("href", 'https://appended-url.com/' + _href);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your `load()` content is being browser cached and apparent as content on the page once you hit the back button.

However before this, on initial page load, your document is complete, and runs your each, but the load isn't complete. In that scenario your content wouldn't be updated.

I'd  rather update the URLs via the load complete callback:

```
$('#div').load('http://myurl', function(res, status, xhr){
    //You can use the parameters for any sort of conditionals
    $('a').each(function(){
      //your code to edit the URLs
    });
});
```